# Git sync says ahead by 1 commit and behind by 4 commits

Tags: git, version-control, github

I tried pushing my code to git account through gitHub desktop app. I'm constantly getting error - "ahead by 1 commit, behind by 4 commits" and it gives me an option to open shell and resolve. I'm not sure on how this can be resolved. Any help would be appreciated.

PS: I'm the only developer and I just want my complete code to be pushed to online. I can ignore what is available on online repo currently. I shouldn't lose my local code if any updates are done from git commands and at the same time I can't restart a completely new repo, as my repo holds tracking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error means two things

- your local branch is 1 commit ahead of the last sync point with the remote branch
- the remote branch has 4 commit since the last sync point with the local branch

In order to resolve this you need to merge the remote branch state into your local branch and then push the new state up to the remote.  There are 2 ways to resolve this

- rebase your branch off of the remote
- a simple `git merge` with remote

Comment: Will any of these commands wipe my local code?  I just want to merge my code with git online repo. Can you share some quick commands?

Comment: @talk2sharn no, neither will wipe out the local code.  It will instead merge your changes with the remote changes.  In general hte merge route is a simple `git merge origin/master` command

Comment: Thank you very much. Git merge worked after a bit of struggling.